# Manually parsing parameters from put request in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have some javascript that uses PUT requests and I'd like to be able to use request.getParameter() to read in variables. I know that Java EE does not parse stuff from PUT requests because HTML PUT was originally intended for file upload. However I am wondering if there is a way to force this behavior anyway or at a minimum how to access the parser Tomcat uses when it parses requests for POST and run it myself on the raw request string.

Thanks.

Comment: Servlets do support PUT requests through the [`HttpServlet#doPut`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doPut%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29).

Comment: I know, and I am getting the PUT request. The problem is that it doesn't parse the form data I send.

Comment: What's the encoding of the form? multipart/form-data or application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

Comment: The latter: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Comment: You should be able to retrieve the form data through HttpServlet, like mentioned by @LuiggiMendoza. Are you sure your javascript is actually sending the form data as you expect?

Comment: Retrieval isn't the question. It's parsing. Tomcat doesn't put the form data in request.parameterMap. What I want to know is how to force tomcat to do this or use whatever lib Tomcat uses and do it myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution appears to be to add the following attribute to the Connector element of server.xml:

```
parseBodyMethods="POST, PUT"
```

This tells Tomcat to treat PUT requests like POST requests with respect to parsing the body.